# Return information on Azure LoadBalancer with Azure Python SDK

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to return a list (Python dictionary) for an Azure LoadBalancer

Dict must contain a few items
FrontEndIP's
Backend Pools
Probes
Rules

Any idea how I might go about this?
Thanks

Comment: Hello @linuxonamission, this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.networkmanagementclient?view=azure-python) might help you , you need to use `networkmanagementclient` and operations will be `load_balancer_backend_address_pools`,`load_balancer_frontend_ip_configurations`,`load_balancer_probes`,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello @linuxonamission, if the below posted answer resolves your issue , please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Stated by AnsumanBal-MT, Using NetworkManagementClient class we have created the below python script which will check whether any load balancer present in that particular resource group , if yes , the script will pull load balancer backend address pools,frontend_ip_configurations & loadbalancer probres under a particular resource group.

```html
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt import resource
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient, resources
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient 
from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials
import os

credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = "<subscriptionID>"
resource_group= '<ResourcegroupName>'
resouce_client=ResourceManagementClient(credential,subscription_id)
network_client=NetworkManagementClient(credential,subscription_id)
resouce_list=resouce_client.resources.list_by_resource_group(resource_group)
for resource in list (resouce_list) :
    if(resource.type == 'Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers'):
        addresspool=network_client.load_balancer_backend_address_pools.list(resource_group_name=resource_group,load_balancer_name=resource.name)
        probes=network_client.load_balancer_probes.list(resource_group_name=resource_group,load_balancer_name=resource.name)
        ipconfig=network_client.load_balancer_frontend_ip_configurations.list(resource_group_name=resource_group,load_balancer_name=resource.name)
        print(*addresspool,*probes,*ipconfig)
```

Here is the sample output for reference:

[image]